# Templating with JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to JQuery Mobile and need to build a fairly large mobile website with it (15+ pages).  My problem is that I cannot seem to figure out how to template with JQuery Mobile. Example: I don't want to have all of my JavaScript and CSS includes in  on EVERY page, for example. I would like a template that all of my pages reference, so when I need to add a new include, I just add it to this template.

I come from an ASP.NET background, so in ASP.NET I would just create a Master Page, but I can't figure an equivalent to this in JQuery Mobile html pages.

Thank you in advance.

edit: I am using JQuery Mobile with PhoneGap/Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your application using RequireJS, Backbone and jQuery Mobile. RequireJS is a Javascript and module loader, and Backbone provides models with key-value bindings, collections and views.

[Here](http://www.appliness.com/getting-started-with-html-mobile-application-development-using-jquery-mobile-requirejs-and-backbonejs) is a simple tutorial to start developing your application using Phonegap.

Comment: Thanks. I am using PhoneGap as a platform. Any idea if JQM + RequireJS + Backbone will work with PhoneGap?

Comment: If you have read the tutorial, you would have seen that the author uses phonegap too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Phonegap you may as well put all the HTML into a single file (your links would be id selectors - href="#contact").

Then for some basic templating I am currently working on a Phonegap/JQM app that reuses the header, footer and sidebar HTML between pages by copying a HTML footer, header and sidebar onto each page at runtime.

So my html looks something like this:

```
<!-- reusable content - this is added to pages using JS -->

<div style="display:none">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="mainheader" data-id="mainheader">
        <h1>App Name/h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="mainfooter">
        <div data-role="navbar" class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#contact" data-parent="contact">Contact</a></li>
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->

    <div data-role="panel" class="sidebar" data-position="left">
        <!-- sidebar content -->
    </div>
</div>

<!-- /end of reusable content -->


<div id="cars" class="content-page" data-role="page">

    <!-- header gets added here -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <!-- page content would go here -->
    </div>

    <!-- footer and sidebar get added here -->

</div>
```

and in my JS looks like this:

```
initializeReusableContent : function () {
    //make sure the panels and nav bar are on each page
    var header, footer, sidebar;

    header = $('.mainheader').remove();
    footer = $('.footer').remove();
    sidebar = $('.sidebar').remove();

    $(".content-page[data-role=page]").prepend(header).append(footer).append(sidebar);
},
```

You could then use something like https://github.com/janl/mustache.js for your content templating.

If you have more complicated needs a templating language would probably better (Backbone, Angular etc).